# Generic constructor allow int type

Tags: java, generics

I have the following setup:

```
class Variable<T> {

    protected T value;

    public Variable(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And I would like to make an `Integer` class that extends `Variable` where I can pass in an `int` to the `Integer` constructor. This is my `Integer` class as it currently stands:

```
class Integer<T> extends Variable<T> {

    public Integer(T value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

Now what I want to be able to do is create a new `Integer` object like this:

```
Integer a = new Integer(5);
```

This works correctly, but I get a warning telling me I should add an annotation to suppress the raw type of `a`. From what I understand about generics, I would think this would work fine without any warnings or suppression needed. How can I change my code so that `Integer` can take in an `int` type without suppression?

Comment: Why is `Integer` generic?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Because if I try to pass an 'int' type to the 'Variable' constructor I get an error telling me the constructor is undefined.

Comment: What? Pass it to the constructor how? You've declared `Integer` as a generic class, why? What makes an `Integer` generic?

Comment: `int` is a primitive type, so you can't use it as an object of a class type. Your code works because of auto-boxing, a functionality that is present in Java since version 5. Auto-boxing translate for you primitive type from and to their wrapper classes, such as `Integer`, `Short`, etc..

Comment: I am trying to pass a variable of type 'int' to the super class 'Variable'. `Integer' is generic because otherwise I get suppress warnings on `Integer` for not adding a parameter of `<T>` to `Integer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Integer` should not be generic, assuming you meant for it to represent a variable of Java's `Integer` type

```
class Integer extends Variable<java.lang.Integer> {
    public Integer(java.lang.Integer value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was confused. I kept my `Integer` constructor the same, though, and am still passing in the primitive type `int` and it works fine. Any idea why it works?

Comment: @opiop65 [Autoboxing and Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Answer (score 4):

Your `Integer` class doesn't make sense being generic. If it were, you'd be able to create stuff like `new Integer<String>()`, which is really strange.

You'd rather need this:

```
class Integer extends Variable<java.lang.Integer> {

    public Integer(java.lang.Integer value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was confused and forgot!

Answer (score 2):

Side note: `Integer` is a bad name choice - it induces way too much confusion with the built-in [`java.lang.Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html). Having said that, you shouldn't make your `Integer` class generic - it's a specific usecase:

```
class Integer extends Variable<java.lang.Integer> {
    public Integer(java.lang.Integer value) {
        super(value);
    }

    // rest of the class...
```

Comment: You're right, I'll change the name. Thanks for the suggestion and the answer, generics make much more sense now...